# How do I turn on phonetic typing for Tamil?

Tags: internationalization

1. Is phonetic typing for Tamil available in Ubuntu 12.04?
2. How can I install it?

Comment: http://mmauran.net/blog/?p=102 - I got the solution. Thanks all who viewed.

Comment: @Zanna does this work for you? Also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus-m17n/+bug/1674089?comments=all&_ga=2.227245661.1355081938.1598724095-1259412518.1576943832

Answer (score 11):

*[ There is an [updated answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/628919) for Ubuntu 14.04+. ]*

Yes. You can type Tamil phonetically in Ubuntu 12.04.

Install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install m17n-db m17n-contrib ibus-m17n
```

You might have to log out and back in to see the various layouts.

---

To enable phonetic typing for Tamil, search for *Keyboard input methods* in the dash and open it.

Go to *Input method* tab and click on *Select an Input method*. Scroll down to Tamil and you will have a couple of options to install. Choose Phonetic from the list and install it.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+Space to start using தமிழ் phonetic and also to revert to English.

Comment: Thanks for that. If either of the answer helped you, consider accepting the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer with screenshots. but by default we don't have all the keyboard layouts listed. looks like the other answer points to the post which points out the packages to install to get the relevant keyboards (including phonetic and tamil99)

Comment: @ragu.pattabi Let me know how I can improve my answer if you find out the relevant package. Thanks.

Comment: as per the article pointed out in the other answer, the packages are 'm17n-db m17n-contrib ibus-m17n' (of course, apt-get install). I needed to logout and log back in to see the layouts.

Comment: phonetic-ஐ விட தமிழ்99 keyboard layout சிறந்தது. கற்றுக் கொள்வது எளிது. தமிழை தமிழிலேயே அடிக்கலாம். தங்கிலீஷில் தட்டுவது சற்று கேவலம் என்பதை விட ஒரு தமிழ் வார்த்தை தட்ட அதிக விசைகளை தட்ட வேண்டியிருக்கிறது. தமிழ்99 பற்றி மேலும் http://tamil99.org/

Comment: @jokerdino For Bangla "Probhat" is more closer to phonetic style. Though it has some own settins. খুব ভালো

Comment: I finally get the familiar settings 'avro-phonetic' from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/137419/61218), of course for Bangla

Answer (score 10):

These are the steps for Ubuntu 14.04:

- Install the `ibus-m17n` package:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ibus-m17n
  ```
- Log out and log in again.
- Select the **Tamil (phonetic (m17n)) (IBus)** option in Text Entry.