# How do I add Bengali support?

Tags: ibus, internationalization

How to type Bengali using Ubuntu 12.04. I had installed IBus but unable to find the list of languages from the drop down list when I try to add Bengali through input method.

Answer (score 7):

For Bengali you can use avro phonetic.

**Method 1**

Using `ibus` as input method, you can try with avro m17n package.It works like charm. You can download from [here](https://github.com/avro-phonetic/Avro-Phonetic-m17n) . While installing you might get packaging warning. Ignore that.

- Download the latest dev file, install it.(Read the instruction in `README` and `Install.txt`)
- Install `ibus-m17n` from software center.
- Switch input method to ibus and configure ibus like this. You can also install hindi from here. (I never tried)
- Log out and login. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>space</kbd> to switch input methods. To change keyboard shortcut, use `General` tab of the shown picture.

[image: Configure input methods]

**Add ibus in start up**

Courtesy - https://askubuntu.com/a/135566/35775

- Open startup applications from the power cog
  [image: powercog]
- Add `ibus-daemon`
  [image: add-button]
  [image: add-dialog]

**Method 2**

Traditionally avro is instructed to setup with `scim` input method. But it doesn't work well in latest ubuntu version (>= 11.10). A ppa package is available (tutorial [here](http://kaustav.codebinders.com/2011/05/install-avro-phonetic-scim-avro-in-ubuntu-from-ppa.html)) also or can compile for [source](http://code.google.com/p/scim-avro/).