# ibus symbol disappears for Japanese language selection

Tags: ibus, japanese

Similar to this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/71177/no-ibus-icon-in-kubuntu, I have trouble with the ibus icon in Ubuntu 12.04. Each time an update is installed, the language selector for Japanese disappears from the top panel. I need to uninstall and install Japanese again, then reboot, to make the symbol appear again. In this thread [No iBus icon in Kubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138406/no-ibus-icon-in-kubuntu-12-04) the suggestion was to install the Japanese Version of Ubuntu, but is it really true that one has to stick to a special version of Ubuntu to get this problem solved?
If so, how can I transfer the settings easily from the current version to the Japanese one?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vanilla Ubuntu, maybe you can try this command when the ibus indicator disappears.

```
ibus-daemon -drx
```

If you are using Kubuntu, make sure that you have `gnome-icon-theme` installed.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-icon-theme
```